# Youtube API > Videos Search > lr parameter not work

Tags: youtube-api

Since today :

"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=nexus&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&lr=fr"

Give me no results, where as "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=nexus&orderby=relevance&start-index=1&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc" does return results.

I notice it's working on my home laptop, but not on my production server. Is it possible youtube blacklist my server IP ? But I got result w/o LR parameter ......

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it,

gdata.youtube.com => has lot of IPs and 1 of range is buggy ;-(

So the solution was to edit /etc/hosts and manually enter my home youtube IP on the server.